# Series of $\sin(nx)$ terms that sum up to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Working in $\mathbb{R}$, what sequences $a_n$ satisfy $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \sin(nx)=0$ for all $x$, pointwise ?

I've never thought about this and I'm not sure whether I'm not missing something trivial - I would have expected that $a_n = 0$ for all $n$ is the only solution, but I'm not sure I've seen this stated anywhere.

Comment: Fourier series. They're linearly independent, even with infinitely many terms.

Comment: But what justifies exchanging the integral and sum order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Riemann's uniqueness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_of_uniqueness) says that if a trigonometric series converges pointwise to $0$, then its coefficients are all equal to $0$. This was later generalized by Cantor, leading him to the development of set theory.

Answer (score 2):

It may depend on the meaning of the summation (and, as a consequence, the speed of the decay of $a$).

To solve all convergence problems, we assume that the series converges normally on $\mathbb{R}$, ie $a \in \ell^1$.

Let then $f(x)=\sum_n{a_n\sin(nx)}$. $f$ is continuous.

I suggest that you compute $\int_0^{2\pi}{f(x)\sin(nx)\,dx}$ as a function of $a_n$ (using the normal convergence of the series).

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what sort of approach to take here - exchanging the integral and sum signs would of course solve the problem, but I don't see how the use of this is justified. Uniform convergence would be enough, but I don't see how $\sum a_n \sin(nx)=0$ pointwise implies that this convergence is necessarily uniform. The general Lebesgue theorem I know concerning this requires some sort of bound on absolute value of the partial sums, or for example that $\sum_n \int |f_n| < \infty$.